# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' in custom loss function (Tensorflow 2.1.0)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, loss-function, loss

I want to train a model with a custom loss function, in order to do that, I need to convert the tensor to numpy array inside the method below:

```
def median_loss_estimation(y_true, y_predicted):
    a = y_predicted.numpy()
```

but I have this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Why?
How can I convert the tensor to a numpy array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: put `run_eagerly=True` in `model.compile`!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the right thing, only Tensorflow 2.1 is currently broken in that aspect. This would normally happen if you run the code without eager mode enabled. However, Tensorflow 2 by default runs in eager mode... or at least it should. The issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38038).

There are at least two solutions to this:

1. Install the latest nightly build.
2. Set `model.run_eagerly = True`.

Comment: using `model.run_eagerly = True` the error remains!

Comment: @FrancescoScala Try then the first option,

Comment: tried: tf `2.0.1`, `2.1.0`, `2.2.0rc2`, `tb-nightly (2.3.0something)` and I got every time the same error!